# Keep line breaks when formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Sometimes, I add linebreaks to make code more readable, or look more uniform. When applying formatting VSCode removes those again when the code fits on a single line. For example (some Dart code)

```
double getQuarterValue(String paramName) => isCorrected(paramName)
    ? state.corrections[paramName].quarterlyValue
    : state.selectedReport.issues[paramName].quarterly;
double getYearValue(String paramName) => isCorrected(paramName)
    ? state.corrections[paramName].yearlyValue
    : state.selectedReport.issues[paramName].yearly;
```

becomes

```
double getQuarterValue(String paramName) => isCorrected(paramName)
    ? state.corrections[paramName].quarterlyValue
    : state.selectedReport.issues[paramName].quarterly;
double getYearValue(String paramName) => isCorrected(paramName) ? state.corrections[paramName].yearlyValue : state.selectedReport.issues[paramName].yearly;
```

Is there a way to prevent VSCode from removing line breaks in code statements when formatting? Eclipse, for example, offers an option called *Never join already wrapped lines* that does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this also applies to Dart code but could well be.

1. Preferences: Open Settings
2. Tab User Settings
3. Extend Extensions
4. Select Dart
5. Search for Wrap options.

### Edit

Looked into the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code) and there doesn't seem te be a setting to change the behavior.
You could open a Issue op [Github](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20wrap)